# Create multiple line charts using Macro in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro which creates line chart for each row. Below is the code.

The data is in following format:

Format in which I have the data:
[image: Format in which I have the data]

```
Sub createChartWithLoop()
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim chrt As Chart
    Set chrt = wks.Shapes.AddChart.Chart

    Dim chartRange As Range
    Set chartRange = wks.Range("A1:A4")

    With chrt
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Range(wks.Range("A" & chartRange.Row & ":D" & chartRange.Row).Address)

        For i = chartRange.Row + 1 To chartRange.Rows.Count
            .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .SeriesCollection(i).Name = wks.Cells(i, 1)
            .SeriesCollection(i).Values = wks.Range("B" & i & ":D" & i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

However, now I have a little different requirement. Assume I have 30 rows same format.

Requirement: I have to consider the first 3 rows as 1 set. 2nd 3 rows as 2nd Set and so on. So here effective we will have 10 set (30 rows/3). Each set should give me a chart.

Right now, I'm getting a chart with 3 lines (3 records). Above is my code. Can anyone help on the above request?

Comment: Do you want to create 10 separate charts from each set?

Comment: @DhirendraKumar Yes, I would ideally want to create a chart for each set. Meaning, here i have 30 rows, which means i have 10 sets of 3 each. Each set will represent a line chart graph with 3 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a procedure which will plot a stated number of charts each using a stated number of rows. Then I wrote a short procedure that shows how to have it create 10 charts with three rows each.

Here is the procedure to create `nCharts` charts, using `nRows` rows for each:

```
Sub CreateChartWithLoop(nCharts As Long, nRows As Long)
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wks = ActiveSheet

    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Dim iChart As Long
    For iChart = 1 To nCharts
        Dim cht As Chart
        Set cht = wks.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, DataRange.Width, DataRange.Rows(1 + (iChart - 1) * nRows).Top).Chart

        Do Until cht.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
          cht.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop

        Dim iRow As Long
        For iRow = 1 To nRows
          With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Name = "=" & DataRange.Cells(iRow + (iChart - 1) * 3, 1).Address(, , , True)
            .Values = DataRange.Rows(iRow + (iChart - 1) * 3).Offset(, 1).Resize(, DataRange.Columns.Count - 1)
          End With
        Next

        cht.HasTitle = True
        cht.ChartTitle.Text = "Chart " & iChart
    Next
End Sub
```

Here's the procedure that calls the main procedure, telling it to make 10 charts with 3 rows each:

```
Sub Create10ChartsWith3RowsEach()
    CreateChartWithLoop 10, 3
End Sub
```